# I can not install puppeteer library

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I used this npm install --save puppeteer to install pupeteer in windows but it does not install this package.this command worked in linux.
Windows 10
node version=v10.16.0

I got these :

puppeteer@1.18.1 install D:\htmltopdf\node_modules\puppeteer

> node install.js

and it stoped at this point and did not download chromiom

Answer (score 0):

it takes a moment at

> node install.js

before showing you that chromium has been downloaded. Its easy to loose track and think nothing is happening, but the packages are being downloaded. Be patient.

Comment: I 'd waited but it does not install chromium,and when i ran it in linux, it worked